# A lower bound of the probability of union $P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let {$E_n$} be events and {$I_n$} their indicators. Prove the inequality
$$
P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k)\ge \frac{\left(\mathbb{E}(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n I_k)\right)^2}{\mathbb{E}\left((\sum\limits_{k=1}^n I_k)^2\right)}.
$$

---

My approach: Denote $p_k:=P(E_k)=\mathbb{E}(I_k)$. Expand the RHS
$$
RHS=\frac{(\sum p_k)^2}{\sum p_k+2\sum_{i<j} P(E_i\cap E_j)}
$$
and apply Inclusion–exclusion principle on LHS
$$
LHS\ge \sum p_k - \sum_{i<j}P(E_i\cap E_j) \quad(*)
$$
We can finally reduce the original inequality to $\sum p_k\ge 2\sum_{i<j}P(E_i\cap E_j)$, which, however, we can easily disprove.

I know the problem occurs at $(*)$, which is too loose. But I have no idea how to go further.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \sum_{k} I_k$ and $Y$ such that, for $1 \le k \le n$

$$P\left[Y = k\right] = \frac{\mathbb P\left[X=k\right]}{\mathbb P\left[X> 0\right]}$$

then $\mathbb E\left[Y\right] = \frac1{\mathbb P\left[X > 0\right]}\mathbb E\left[X\right]$ and $\mathbb E\left[Y^2\right] = \frac1{\mathbb P\left[X > 0\right]}\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$ using $$\text{Var}[Y] = \mathbb E\left[Y^2\right] - \mathbb E\left[Y\right]^2 \ge 0$$ so $$\frac{1}{\mathbb P\left[X>0\right]^2} \mathbb E\left[X\right]^2 \le \frac1{\mathbb P\left[X > 0\right]} \mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$$

finally, $$\mathbb P\left[X >0\right] \ge \frac{\mathbb E\left[X\right]^2}{\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]}$$

Can you finish the proof?

Comment: Thanks, I got it. The helper r.v. $Y$ is impressive.

Comment: It is a well known trick

Answer (score 1):

It follows from [the second moment method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_method), which states  that for a non-negative random variable $X$ with finite variance:

$$\mathbb P( X > 0 )
\ge \frac{(\operatorname{E}[X])^2}{\operatorname{E}[X^2]}.$$

By defining

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_i,$$ and noting that

$$\mathbb P(\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k)=\mathbb P(X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_i>0)\ge \frac{(\operatorname{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_i])^2}{\operatorname{E}[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}I_i)^2]}$$

the result is obtaind.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I can only accept one answer, so it went to the former XD